# CAKEPHP SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cms_database.users' doesn't exist. iam using cakephp 4

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cms_database.users' doesn't exist

Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables?
Some of the Table objects in your application were created by instantiating "Cake\ORM\Table" instead of any other specific subclass.

This could be the cause for this exception. Auto-Tables are created for you under the following circumstances:

The class for the specified table does not exist.
The Table was created with a typo: $this->getTableLocator()->get('Atricles');
The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends Table
The file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.php
The Table was used using associations but the association has a typo: $this->belongsTo('Atricles')
The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.

Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

Users

Comment: Does the table "users" exist in your "cms_database" database?

Comment: i am using different table name admins.. and i also define 'userModel' => 'Admins',  and above error are solved. But  now i am getting invalid user name and password  error every time even details are correct..

Comment: Are the passwords in your database hashed?

Comment: yes password is hash.. by the help of default password hash.. i just need to change default users table to admin table. how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concern..

I solved my error..

I place this resolver method code in my Application.php file to change default users table to admins table. here is the code-

```
$authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
    'fields' => [
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        
    ],
    
    'resolver' => [
    'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
    'userModel' => 'Admins',
    ]
]);
```